# Customized sprintf,is it worth the effort?

Tags: c, printf

The code below is extracted from nginx,which basically rewrites `sprintf`,in fact nginx also rewrites some other string functions,is it worth the effort?

```
u_char *
ngx_vslprintf(u_char *buf, u_char *last, const char *fmt, va_list args)
{
    u_char                *p, zero;
    int                    d;
    double                 f, scale;
    size_t                 len, slen;
    int64_t                i64;
    uint64_t               ui64;
    ngx_msec_t             ms;
    ngx_uint_t             width, sign, hex, max_width, frac_width, n;
    ngx_str_t             *v;
    ngx_variable_value_t  *vv;

    while (*fmt && buf < last) {

        /*
         * "buf < last" means that we could copy at least one character:
         * the plain character, "%%", "%c", and minus without the checking
         */

        if (*fmt == '%') {

            i64 = 0;
            ui64 = 0;

            zero = (u_char) ((*++fmt == '0') ? '0' : ' ');
            width = 0;
            sign = 1;
            hex = 0;
            max_width = 0;
            frac_width = 0;
            slen = (size_t) -1;

            while (*fmt >= '0' && *fmt <= '9') {
                width = width * 10 + *fmt++ - '0';
            }


            for ( ;; ) {
                switch (*fmt) {

                case 'u':
                    sign = 0;
                    fmt++;
                    continue;

                case 'm':
                    max_width = 1;
                    fmt++;
                    continue;

                case 'X':
                    hex = 2;
                    sign = 0;
                    fmt++;
                    continue;

                case 'x':
                    hex = 1;
                    sign = 0;
                    fmt++;
                    continue;

                case '.':
                    fmt++;

                    while (*fmt >= '0' && *fmt <= '9') {
                        frac_width = frac_width * 10 + *fmt++ - '0';
                    }

                    break;

                case '*':
                    slen = va_arg(args, size_t);
                    fmt++;
                    continue;

                default:
                    break;
                }

                break;
            }


            switch (*fmt) {

            case 'V':
                v = va_arg(args, ngx_str_t *);

                len = ngx_min(((size_t) (last - buf)), v->len);
                buf = ngx_cpymem(buf, v->data, len);
                fmt++;

                continue;

            case 'v':
                vv = va_arg(args, ngx_variable_value_t *);

                len = ngx_min(((size_t) (last - buf)), vv->len);
                buf = ngx_cpymem(buf, vv->data, len);
                fmt++;

                continue;

            case 's':
                p = va_arg(args, u_char *);

                if (slen == (size_t) -1) {
                    while (*p && buf < last) {
                        *buf++ = *p++;
                    }

                } else {
                    len = ngx_min(((size_t) (last - buf)), slen);
                    buf = ngx_cpymem(buf, p, len);
                }

                fmt++;

                continue;

            case 'O':
                i64 = (int64_t) va_arg(args, off_t);
                sign = 1;
                break;

            case 'P':
                i64 = (int64_t) va_arg(args, ngx_pid_t);
                sign = 1;
                break;

            case 'T':
                i64 = (int64_t) va_arg(args, time_t);
                sign = 1;
                break;

            case 'M':
                ms = (ngx_msec_t) va_arg(args, ngx_msec_t);
                if ((ngx_msec_int_t) ms == -1) {
                    sign = 1;
                    i64 = -1;
                } else {
                    sign = 0;
                    ui64 = (uint64_t) ms;
                }
                break;

            case 'z':
                if (sign) {
                    i64 = (int64_t) va_arg(args, ssize_t);
                } else {
                    ui64 = (uint64_t) va_arg(args, size_t);
                }
                break;

            case 'i':
                if (sign) {
                    i64 = (int64_t) va_arg(args, ngx_int_t);
                } else {
                    ui64 = (uint64_t) va_arg(args, ngx_uint_t);
                }

                if (max_width) {
                    width = NGX_INT_T_LEN;
                }

                break;

            case 'd':
                if (sign) {
                    i64 = (int64_t) va_arg(args, int);
                } else {
                    ui64 = (uint64_t) va_arg(args, u_int);
                }
                break;

            case 'l':
                if (sign) {
                    i64 = (int64_t) va_arg(args, long);
                } else {
                    ui64 = (uint64_t) va_arg(args, u_long);
                }
                break;

            case 'D':
                if (sign) {
                    i64 = (int64_t) va_arg(args, int32_t);
                } else {
                    ui64 = (uint64_t) va_arg(args, uint32_t);
                }
                break;

            case 'L':
                if (sign) {
                    i64 = va_arg(args, int64_t);
                } else {
                    ui64 = va_arg(args, uint64_t);
                }
                break;

            case 'A':
                if (sign) {
                    i64 = (int64_t) va_arg(args, ngx_atomic_int_t);
                } else {
                    ui64 = (uint64_t) va_arg(args, ngx_atomic_uint_t);
                }

                if (max_width) {
                    width = NGX_ATOMIC_T_LEN;
                }

                break;

            case 'f':
                f = va_arg(args, double);

                if (f < 0) {
                    *buf++ = '-';
                    f = -f;
                }

                ui64 = (int64_t) f;

                buf = ngx_sprintf_num(buf, last, ui64, zero, 0, width);

                if (frac_width) {

                    if (buf < last) {
                        *buf++ = '.';
                    }

                    scale = 1.0;

                    for (n = frac_width; n; n--) {
                        scale *= 10.0;
                    }

                    /*
                     * (int64_t) cast is required for msvc6:
                     * it can not convert uint64_t to double
                     */
                    ui64 = (uint64_t) ((f - (int64_t) ui64) * scale + 0.5);

                    buf = ngx_sprintf_num(buf, last, ui64, '0', 0, frac_width);
                }

                fmt++;

                continue;

#if !(NGX_WIN32)
            case 'r':
                i64 = (int64_t) va_arg(args, rlim_t);
                sign = 1;
                break;
#endif

            case 'p':
                ui64 = (uintptr_t) va_arg(args, void *);
                hex = 2;
                sign = 0;
                zero = '0';
                width = NGX_PTR_SIZE * 2;
                break;

            case 'c':
                d = va_arg(args, int);
                *buf++ = (u_char) (d & 0xff);
                fmt++;

                continue;

            case 'Z':
                *buf++ = '\0';
                fmt++;

                continue;

            case 'N':
#if (NGX_WIN32)
                *buf++ = CR;
#endif
                *buf++ = LF;
                fmt++;

                continue;

            case '%':
                *buf++ = '%';
                fmt++;

                continue;

            default:
                *buf++ = *fmt++;

                continue;
            }

            if (sign) {
                if (i64 < 0) {
                    *buf++ = '-';
                    ui64 = (uint64_t) -i64;

                } else {
                    ui64 = (uint64_t) i64;
                }
            }

            buf = ngx_sprintf_num(buf, last, ui64, zero, hex, width);

            fmt++;

        } else {
            *buf++ = *fmt++;
        }
    }

    return buf;
}
```

IMO writing similar stuff only causes waste of memory,your idea?

Comment: Is this actually the same as `sprintf`, or a slight variation?

Comment: nginx also target embedded platforms. For the web server in your fridge, being as self contained as possible may be advantageous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this kind of thing is not only wasteful but actively harmful. The name includes `printf`, which would lead a reasonable person first seeing code that's using it to assume its format strings are `printf`-compatible. But in fact they're only a very poor approximation of `printf` semantics. This could lead to extremely serious, security-critical bugs, which might go undetected if the code only appears in a non-common-usage case. The C standard has a perfectly safe and usable `snprintf` function which should always be used when this functionality is needed. And shame on whoever designed this junk in the name of "security"...

Answer (score 3):

Whether it's "worth it" is subjective - there are lots of things to consider:

1. What advantages does it give over `sprintf`? Do you need them?
2. Are you willing to live with whatever shortcomings may be there?
3. Do you understand the code well enough to be able to fix it if problems are found?
4. Is it as fast as `sprintf`? If not, do you care?

You may also want to consider writing a cover function that adds whatever extra functionality you need but then just calls `sprintf`, rather than re-implement the entire function.